# При выводе в конец строки добавляется возврат каретки

Tags: python

Считываю стоку из файла где есть пустые значения через `split(\t)`. При выводе у последнего значения modification date добавляется символ переноса строки, однако если обратиться к нему, то вернет строку без \n

```
 def get_str(self) -> list:
    file_name = 'test.txt'
    cities = []
    data = {}
    info_list = [
        "geonameid",
        "name",
        "asciiname",
        "alternatenames",
        "latitude",
        "longitude",
        "feature class",
        "feature code",
        "country code",
        "cc2",
        "admin1 code",
        "admin2 code",
        "admin3 code",
        "admin4 code",
        "population",
        "elevation",
        "dem",
        "timezone",
        "modification date"
    ]

    with open(file_name, encoding="utf-8") as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.split('\t')
            data = dict(zip(info_list, line))
            cities.append(data)
    
    return cities

вывод

 'modification date': '2011-07-09\n'
```

как от этого можно избавиться или это нормально ?

Comment: как я понял это последний элемент строки `modification date` , если `line` его содержит можно сделать либо реплейс либо срез без последнего символа, до `split`

Comment: "однако если обратиться к нему, то вернет строку без \n" - это кажется